# I can't access my Windows 10 through GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode, and after that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in legacy / BIOS mode.

Now the problem is I can't access my dual boot with GRUB. In both operating systems but I can open individually with UEFI mode and BIOS.

I've run the command `sudo apt-get install grub` but no changes occurred.

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. You can only boot from UEFI boot menu as once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or from grub menu you can only boot systems installed in same boot mode as grub/Ubuntu. You can use Boot-Repair in UEFI mode to convert Ubuntu to UEFI boot mode without total reinstall. It just installs the UEFI version of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Your comment is really the answer to this question. Would you consider posting it as one? Or is there a good dupe target you know of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/781081/grub2-issues-after-16-04-lts-fresh-install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub2 Issues After 16.04 LTS Fresh Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781081/grub2-issues-after-16-04-lts-fresh-install)

Answer (score -1):

What i understand out of your question is that the Windows 10 OS is not visible in the grub menu.

Try using `sudo grub-update` in the ubuntu terminal and see if that helps.

Comment: That won't work; the problem is that UEFI and legacy mode can't work together in the way OP wants. This always arises when mixing firmware modes.